# Metrizability of the finite complement topology on an infinite set

Tags: general-topology

`The finite complement topology on an infinite set is not metrizable`

In my unfortunately illegible notes I have the answer down as true, but I can't decipher my reasoning. Next to "true" I have written $$x_n \in X, \text{ limit } X.$$

I suspect that it's something to do with being Hausdorff or something sequential?
know that other proofs for this exist, but I would ideally like to decipher this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is that given a sequence $x_n $ which has no repeating terms, that sequence converges to every point in $X $ (so you wrote that the limit is $X$), Thus, the space is not Hausdorff.